# File paths and local macros

Tags: stata, stata-macros

Suppose that I am in a folder `~/top`. 
There is a file path like this: `~/top/middle/bottom folder`.

I want to define a local macro and then use it in the file path.

What I have done is the following:

```
local target ""bottom folder""
cd "middle"
cd `target'
```

This works fine but I can't figure out how to combine lines two and three into a single line.

I have tried `` cd "middle/`target'" `` and`` cd ""middle/"+`target'" `` but these are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are already in the directory `top`, the following should work:

```
local target bottom folder
cd "middle/`target'"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I guess I should just avoid this in the future by omitting spaces from my folder and file names!

Comment: The problem was that you were using two sets of quotes in `local`. You only needed one or none at all.